# Changing the tags with the text between the tags

Tags: javascript, regex

My title sounds complicated so i'll try to simplify it by making an example

i have these selfmade tags like

```
{tag}tagtext{tag}
```

and i'm trying to change this into

```
<span>same tagtext</span>
```

i tried using regex but i couldn't really figure out how could i get the text between the tags and then also change the tags to something else.

i got the text between the tags with

```
string.match('{tag}(.*){tag}');
```

Also all the tags are same and for some reason the match function gave me only the first result it found. I guess it has something to do with my regex.

Also i do not want to do it with a loop because it will start to work as an live editor and i need to keep the performace fast.

Comment: If you could change the tag notation to something like <your-tag>Content</your-tag>, then the text could be parsed as XML and a JSON encoded string could be retrieved. You might find this helpful https://github.com/abdmob/x2js

Comment: you need to use `/g` to match more than the 1st result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(\{tag\})(.*?)\1/g
 ^^^^^^^^^  ^^ ^^ ^  
    1        2  3 4
1: Match tag and put in group 1
2: *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
3: matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
4: Global pattern flags, all matches.
```

```js
var temp = "{tag}tagtext1{tag}{tag}tagtext2{tag}\n{tag}tagtext3{tag}{tag}tagtext4{tag}";
console.log(temp.replace(/(\{tag\})(.*?)\1/g,"<span>$2</span>"));
```

Is this your expect result ?

```
<span>tagtext1</span><span>tagtext2</span>
<span>tagtext3</span><span>tagtext4</span>
```

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what i was looking. Thank you! I'm still learning to use regex expressions, it's seems so complicated. Would you mind explaining your code?? if not, it's okay :)

Comment: And many website have the standard explanation. [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the global modifier or g after a RegEx expression in order to enable all matches. What language are you using for RegEx?